# String comparison regardless of case

Tags: php, string-matching, case-insensitive

I'm trying to find different variations of "Username" or "Password" , as shown below, in an case-insensitive manner:

```
$unVar1 = "username";
$unVar2 = "user name";
$usernameVariations1 = strcasecmp($unVar1, $unVar2);

$unVar3 = "User";
$unVar4 = "id";
$usernameVariations2 = strcasecmp($unVar3, $unVar4);

$pwVar1 = "password";
$pwVar2 = "pass";
$passwordVariations1 = strcasecmp($pwVar1, $pwVar2);

if ($element->value === $usernameVariations1
   || $element->value === $usernameVariations2
   || $element->value === $passwordVariations1) {
  echo "Weee!";
}
else {
  echo "boo!";
}
```

The problem is it outputs "`boo`" for each element in the `foreach()` output. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to put all of these values in an array? Thanks.

Comment: There is no `foreach` loop in what you're posting and generally your code is very confusing. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Missing some code here, sorry for confusion @kba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated then it needs to be. If your usernames and passwords not case sensitive, just make them lowercase when you compare them:

```
if (strtolower($username) === strtolower($element->value))
{
     // ok
}
```

Now if you're allowing spaces to be added to the middle, and abbreviations, then you can try plan B:

```
$valid_usernames = array('Username', 'username', 'user name', 'UsE Nam');
if (in_array($element->value, $valid_usernames))
{
     // ok
}
```

Keep in mind that you are now responsible for keeping `$valid_usernames` complete.

Comment: Is it easy to then implement strtolower() in the example 2?

Comment: Can I do something like :
if (in_array(strtolower($element->value), strtolower($valid_usernames))){}     ?